# Dynamically numbering distinct sql rows in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

How would I dynamically number rows in a query similar to this:

```
Select distinct name from @table where %rules
```

When I add ROW_NUMBER() OVER() I lose my distinct property, and it returns every element in table, with a unique row number.

```
Select distinct ROW_NUMBER OVER(order by name), name from @table where %rules
```

I don't want to create a temporary table, otherwise I would make a primary key for the temporary table and have it insert row numbers that way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like this.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by name), * from 
(Select distinct name from @table where %rules) as mytable
```

Comment: or a CTE version, if people prefer the syntax :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c33c4/3